# Regular Expression to split a sting

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like 
[123,234,321,....]

Can i use a regular  expression to extract only the numbers ?

this is the code i am using now

```
 public static string[] Split()
    {
        string s = "[123,234,345,456,567,678,789,890,100]";
        var temp = s.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "");
        char[] separator = { ',' };
        return temp.Split(separator);

    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: Yes, you can. However, I'd just like to say this is exactly how I'd code it, your solution is perfectly fine and I'd probably prefer it to the RegExp approach

Answer (score 2):

You can use `string.Split` for this - no need for a regular expression, though your code can be simplified:

```
var nums = s.Split('[', ']', ',');
```

Thought you may want to exclude empty entries in the returned array:

```
var nums = s.Split(new[] { '[', ']', ',' }, 
                   StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: while this might be good advice, its not what the question asked.

Comment: @Keith - I believe that looking beyond the actual question to the actual requirement and how best to resolve it is giving the best answer I can.

Answer (score 1):

There's an overload to Trim() that takes a character.

You could do this.

```
string s = "[123,234,345,456,567,678,789,890,100]";
var nums = s.Trim('[').Trim(']').Split(',');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a regular expression, try:

```
string s = "[123,234,345,456,567,678,789,890,100]";            
var matches = Regex.Matches(s, @"[0-9]+", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

However, regular expressions tend to make your code less readable, so you might stick with your original approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try with using [`string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method;

```
string s = "[123,234,345,456,567,678,789,890,100]";
var numbers = s.Split('[',']', ',');
foreach(var i in numbers )
   Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/vidlZF).

**EDIT**: As Oded [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15389442/447156), you may want to use [`StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions.aspx) also.

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = "[123,234,345,456,567,678,789,890,100]";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(s, @"(\d+)[,\]]");
string[] result = matches.OfType<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value).ToArray();
```

Here the `@` is used to signify a verbatim string literal and allows the escape character '\' to be used directly in Regular expression notation without escaping itself "\".

`\d` is a digit, `\d+` mean 1 or more digits. The parenthesis signify a group so `(\d+)` means I want a group of digits. (*See group used a little later)

`[,\]]` square brackets, in brief, mean choose any one of my element so it will choose either the comma `,` or a square bracket `]` which I had to escape.

So the regular expression will find the expressions of sequential digits followed by a `,` or `]`. The Matches will return the set of matches (which we use because there are multiple set) then we go through each match - with some LINQ - and grab the index 1 group which is the second group, "But we only made one group?" We only specified one group, the first group (index 0) is the entire regular expression match, which in our case, will include the `,` or `]` which we don't want.

Answer (score 0):

while you can and probably should use string.Split as other answers indicate,  the question specifically asks if you can do it with regex, and yes, you can :-

```
var r = new Regex(@"\d+", RegexOptions.Compiled );
var matches = r.Matches("[123,234,345,456,567,678,789,890,100]");
```

Comment: Note that in .NET regular expressions, `\d` matches on more than `[0-9]` - it will match on any Unicode numeral (say Arabic digits).